# Replace any character before <usernameredacted@example.com> with an empty string

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string

```
     AnyText: "jonathon" <usernameredacted@example.com>
```

Desired Output Using Regex

```
     AnyText: <usernameredacted@example.com>
```

Omit anything in between !

I am still a rookie at regular expressions. Could anyone out there help me with the matching & replacing expression for the above scenario?

Comment: Particularly with regexs, you need to provide sample data.  Input and desired output.

Comment: I changed the presumably real email address to protect the innocent.

Comment: For e.g. Jonathon <username@example.com> to be regex match & regex replace with ""<username@example.com>. Any character before the email,i want it to be replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
string input = "jonathon <usernameredacted@example.com>";
string output = Regex.Match(input, @"<[^>]+>").Groups[0].Value;
Console.WriteLine(output); //<usernameredacted@example.com>
```

Comment: I have this string

     AnyText: "jonathon" <usernameredacted@example.com>

Desired Output Using Regex

     AnyText: <usernameredacted@example.com>

Is there anyway to omit anything in between AnyText: & <usernameredacted@example.com> ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex to match all the characters that you want to replace with an empty string:

```
^[^<]*
```

The first `^` is an anchor to the beginning of the string. The `^` inside the character class means that the character class is a negation. ie. any character that isn't an `<` will match. The `*` is a greedy quantifier. So in summary, this regex will swallow up all characters from the beginning of the string until the first `<`.

Comment: I have this string AnyText: "jonathon" <usernameredacted@example.com> Desired Output Using Regex AnyText: <usernameredacted@example.com> Is there anyway to omit anything in between AnyText: & <usernameredacted@example.com> ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it in VBA flavor: Replace "^[^""]*" with "".

- ^ marks the start of the sentence.
- [^""]* marks anything other than a
  quote sign.

UPDATE: 
Since in your additional comment you mentioned you wanted to grab the "From:" and the email address, but none of the junk in between or after, I figure instead of replace, extract would be better. Here is a VBA function written for Excel that will give you back all the subgroup matches (everything you put in parenthesis) and nothing else.

```
Function RegexExtract(ByVal text As String, _
                      ByVal extract_what As String) As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.Pattern = extract_what
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

For i = 0 To allMatches.Item(0).submatches.count - 1
    result = result & allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(i)
Next

RegexExtract = result
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Using this code, your regex call would be: "^(.+: ).+(<.+>).*"

- ^ denotes start of sentence
- (.+: ) denotes first match group. .+ is one or more characters, followed by : and a space
- .+ denotes one or more characters
- (<.+>) denotes second match group.
  < is <, then .+ for one or more characters, then the final >
- .* denotes zero or more

  characters.

So in excel you'd use (assuming cell is A1):

```
=RegexExtract(A1, "^(.+: ).+(<.+>).*")
```

Comment: Dear Sir, I realised I may have some changes to my question. Example, string input = "From: Jonathon <usernameredatced@example.com> string output = ? My desired output would be (From: <usernameredatced@example.com>) Can u help me with this additional change ?

Comment: Hi Derek, I'm only experienced in VBA, so I wrote up a solution for you above in the update! Hope it helps!