# Replace any character in between AnyText: and <usernameredacted@example.com> with an empty string using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string

```
AnyText: "TomDickHarry" <usernameredacted@example.com>
```

Desired Output Using Regex

```
AnyText: <usernameredacted@example.com>
```

Help to replace anything in between `AnyText:` and `<usernameredacted@example.com>` with an empty string using Regex.

I am still a rookie at regular expressions. Could anyone out there help me with the matching & replacing expression for the above scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace any character before <usernameredacted@example.com> with an empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529471/replace-any-character-before-usernameredactedexample-com-with-an-empty-string)

Comment: This is almost the same as your question from 2 hours ago.

Comment: What additional changes?

Comment: The Desired Output is different. Any character in between must be replaced with an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ABC = "AnyText: \"TomDickHarry\" <usernameredacted@example.com>"
Regex RemoveName = new Regex("(?<=AnyText:).*(?=<)");
string XYZ = RemoveName.Replace(ABC, "");
```

So, this will find a regex match in the string you supplied, and on the third line, replace it with an empty string.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail using code examples? I do not quite catch you.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a more complete solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const string Input = @"AnyText: ""TomDickHarry"" <usernameredacted@example.com>This is.";

var result = Regex.Replace(Input, "(?<=AnyText:)([^<]*)", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
string s = Regex.Replace(Input, ":(.*)<", "");
```